# Why does $f : U\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ holomorphic, U open convex $\Rightarrow F$ exists' apply?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does an antiderivative $F$ of $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ exists for $f$ holomorphic and $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ an open and convex set?

Comment: What sort of "why" are you interested in? Because in a convex set all loops are null-homotopic, and hence all integrals of closed forms depend only on the start and endpoints of the path? Because of Goursat's lemma?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, just those sorts of 'why', thank you! Could you please create an answer out of it, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Goursat's lemma, if $f$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of a triangle $\Delta$, then

$$\int_{\partial\Delta} f(z)\,dz = 0.$$

In a convex domain $U$, for any three points $z_0,z_1,z_2 \in U$, the triangle with vertices $z_0,z_1,z_2$ is contained in $U$, so we have

$$0 = \int_{\partial\Delta} f(z)\,dz = \int_{[z_0,z_1]}f(z)\,dz + \int_{[z_1,z_2]}f(z)\,dz + \int_{[z_2,z_0]}f(z)\,dz,$$

which - using $\int_{[a,b]}f(z)\,dz = -\int_{[b,a]}f(z)\,dz$, where $[a,b]$ denotes the line segment connecting $a$ and $b$, traversed from $a$ to $b$ - after rearranging becomes

$$\int_{[z_0,z_2]} f(z)\,dz - \int_{[z_0,z_1]} f(z)\,dz = \int_{[z_1,z_2]} f(z)\,dz.\tag{1}$$

From this we deduce that for any fixed $z_0\in U$, the function

$$F(z) := \int_{[z_0,z]} f(\zeta)\,d\zeta$$

is differentiable with derivative $f$. Namely, $(1)$ becomes

$$F(z_2) - F(z_1) = \int_{[z_1,z_2]} f(z)\,dz,$$

and with the parametrisation $\gamma(t) = z_1 + t\cdot(z_2-z_1)$ we see

$$\begin{align}
\frac{F(z_2)-F(z_1)}{z_2-z_1} &= \frac{1}{z_2-z_1}\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))\,dt.
\end{align}$$

By the continuity of $f$ in $z_1$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert w-z_1\rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(w)-f(z_1)\rvert < \varepsilon$. So if $\lvert z_2-z_1\rvert < \delta$, we have

$$\left\lvert \frac{F(z_2)-f(z_1)}{z_2-z_1} - f(z_1)\right\rvert = \left\lvert \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))-f(z_1)\,dt\right\rvert \leqslant \int_0^1 \lvert f(\gamma(t)) - f(z_1)\rvert\,dt < \varepsilon,$$

since then also $\lvert \gamma(t)-z_1\rvert < \delta$ for all $0\leqslant t \leqslant 1$. But that means that

$$\lim_{w\to z_1} \frac{F(w)-F(z_1)}{w-z_1} = f(z_1),$$

i.e. $F$ is differentiable in $z_1$ with derivative $f(z_1)$. Since $z_1$ was arbitrary, the global assertion $F' = f$ follows.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce each of your steps. I understand all of those until your conclusion. Why does the first part lead to "[...] which shows that for any fixed $z_0 \in U$, the function[...]"?

Comment: I've explained with more details. If that doesn't clarify all points, ping me, please.

Comment: I do understand it now, thank you very much!